# Proving this sequence is bounded from above

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

My sequence is $a_n = \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+2} + ... +  \frac{1}{2n-1} +  \frac{1}{2n}$ how do I show that it’s bounded from above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $a_n < \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n}$ ($n$ times). Then $a_n < \frac{n}{n} <1$.

Answer (score 1):

Just note that $\frac{1}{n+1}<\frac{1}{n}$